# Mysql + array_intersect styled Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
column1  column2
 1       2,3,4,5,6,7
 2       10,11,1,2,3,4,5
 3       1,2,3,25
 4       20,21,22,23
```

I have a php array like

```
$search = array(5,6,11,2,4,25);
```

I need to get all rows from db_table where any of $search values match with any of column2 (break by comma) values.

So for me expected result is:

```
column 1
1
2
3
```

I am aware that, I can use fulltext search with MATCH AGAINST.
But is there any other way out faster than fulltext search?

Comment: This schema violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and is not going to work well for you. Can you restructure it to make it relational?

Comment: Well, this is temp table created to get huge resultset.. these 2 columns are just part of it.

Comment: If it's temporary, then even more reason to structure it properly. This is a terrible way to organize data in a relational database.